# Does bash come with knoppix 7 and if not is it hard to install?

Tags: linux, bash

Does bash come with knoppix 7 and if not is it hard to install?

I am just learning linux and it seems everyone is suggesting to use bash to learn the command line stuff, but I can't seem to find bash in knoppix 7. (I have found a couple of other terminals, but not bash.)

Thanks in advance for the help!!!

Comment: What 'alternatives'  do you think you have? Because I'm almost certain it's in there, and you probably confuse a terminal emulator (konsole, gnome-terminal, xterm, et al.) with what runs in it (bash/dash/ksh/etc.)

Comment: I have found LXTerminal, UXTerm, XTerm, and Root Shell.

Comment: This question isn't particularly related to programming.  Having said that: Bash is a shell, not a terminal.  Just try typing `bash` at a command prompt.  You're *probably* already using it.

Comment: bash is the default shell for most, perhaps all, Linux distributions. Launch any terminal and type `echo $BASH_VERSION`. Also, `grep $USER /etc/passwd` will show you what your default login shell is (it's the last field of the output).

Comment: Well, I wondered that, but the screen shots usually have 'bash' in the prompt so I wondered if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell

Comment: Almost every desktop-oriented Linux distribution I've seen recently at least has `bash` available, and it's usually the default. That may not be true on some of the minimalist or embedded or other extremely specialized distributions, though.

Comment: The prompt *may or may not* include the word "bash". It's determined by the value of `$PS1`.

Comment: As `larsks` says... just fire up `XTerm` and you are probably in bash already (`echo $SHELL` to check that). If it isn't `bash`, just type `bash` and you're there.

Comment: The echo command worked! 4.2.20 - release Thanks guys for helping me I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

> **Does bash come with knoppix 7**

bash comes with every popular Linux desktop distribution.

Knoppix 7.04 includes bash 4.2 according to [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=knoppix)

> **is it hard to install?**

The easiest way to install a software package is to use the distro's package manager. There's probably a GUI installer but I'd open a terminal window and type

```
sudo apt-get install bash
```

So long as the computer is connected to the internet, that is all you need to do.